# render richfaces popupPanel after bean method is finished

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a simple problem where I want to display a popup if something went wrong in my managed bean.
The bean holds a list of exceptions that can be raised, with getter/setter methods.

The xhtml looks like this

```
      <rich:panel>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:commandButton value="Compute Mission"
            action="#{missionHandler.generateMissionFeasability}"
            render="popupPanel">
        </a4j:commandButton>
    </h:form>
   </rich:panel>
   <rich:popupPanel id="popupPanel" modal="true" autosized="true"
    resizeable="false" moveable="false" rendered="#{not empty    missionHandler.exceptions}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Exceptions raised during the processing    " />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#"
            onclick="#{rich:component('popupPanel')}.hide();return false;">
        </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

As you see I have a command button that should call generateMissionFeasibility method in the bean.
The method will (among other things) add exception in the exceptions list.

I would like to check the list (if it's empty or not) to display the popup

The code above doesn't work because I think the popup is rendered before the end of the method in the bean, and the list is empty at the beginning.

Comment: Try encapsulating panel inside for example `<h:panelGroup id="group">` and change `render` attribute of `commandButton` to `render="group"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't work because the first time the view is about to be rendered, `missionHandler.exceptions` will be empty, which means `popupPanel` never makes it to the browser. Subsequent requests to reRender `popupPanel` will fail as the component is nowhere to be found in the DOM.

For a component to be ajax-updated, it must already be in the DOM in the browser, this is the way ajax works. So the solution is to wrap the content of the popup panel in a component that will always be rendered.

That aside, even if you got the rendering correct, your popup will only be placed in the DOM. You actually need to call `show()` on the popup to get it to showup

To achieve what you want however, a better alternative will be to

1. Conditionally display the popup using javascript. If the condition is met, the `show()` function is called for the popup. Otherwise, an empty, do-nothing javascript function will be called.

   ```
   <a4j:commandButton value="Compute Mission" action="#missionHandler.generateMissionFeasability}"
       oncomplete="#{not empty missionHandler.exceptions ? #{rich:component('popupPanel')}.show()" : doNothing()}" render="popupPanel">
   </a4j:commandButton>
   ```

   For the doNothing js:

   ```
   <script> function doNothing(){} <script/>
   ```
2. Take the rendering condition out of the modal panel

EDIT:  Additionally, the `show` attribute on the popup component can be based on the same EL condition as the `oncomplete` attribute

Answer (score 3):

One way to make popup panel be shown once rendered is to change

```
rendered="#{not empty missionHandler.exceptions}"
```

to

```
show="#{not empty missionHandler.exceptions}"
```